# Angular 2 ngModel value not updating fast enough using ionic

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, ionic2

I have a `ion-searchbar` that looks like this

```
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchQuery" (keyup.enter)="search();"></ion-searchbar>
```

and the `searchQuery` is defined in my typescript file like this

```
export class SearchPage {
  searchQuery: string; 

  constructor(){}

  search() {
   this.service.search(this.searchQuery).subscribe(
     data => this.searchResults = data,
     error => {
       //something
     }, () => {
       //something
     }
   );
  }
 }
```

The problem is that if I change the value too fast and I press Enter, the value of `searchQuery` is not updated. For example, if I search "test" and I wait two seconds it will work. If I then search "testing" and I type it fast and press Enter right away, the value will still be "test". Now, I know this sounds weird, but it is really happening!

Any ideas why the value is not changed as soon as I type something?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In Html try this event change

```
  <form [ngFormModel]="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="search()">
      <ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchQuery" (keyup)="search()"></ion-searchbar>
        <button type="submit" block>Submit</button>
   </form>
```

Even [check here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-preview-app/tree/master/app/pages/searchbars)  might this help

In ts trim the value

```
  this.service.search(this.searchQuery.trim()).subscribe(.....)
```

Comment: this should work, but it looks like a workaround. I'm trying to find a real solution for now.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it, based on the [documentation for ion-searchbar](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/searchbar):

```
<ion-searchbar #searchBar [debounce]="50" (ionChange)="search(searchBar.value)">
</ion-searchbar>
```

and in the TS file:

```
search(value: string) {
    // do something with value
}
```

Explanation:

It's pretty self-explanatory, but here it is. The `#searchBar` creates a 'hook' for the element (sort of a 'self', or 'this', but named). We then use the property `value` from `ion-searchbar` to pass it to our function. The last thing is modifying the `[debounce]` property to make it update faster (but it will trigger more times when people write fast - use with discretion).

Answer (score 0):

Something you can do to improve the way the `search bar` is being handled is:

In your `page.html`:

```
<ion-searchbar primary hideCancelButton [(ngModel)] = "searchQuery" [ngFormControl]="searchQueryControl"></ion-searchbar>
```

And in your `page.ts`:

```
// Remember to import these things:
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, Control} from 'angular2/common';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';

constructor ( ... ) {
    //...
    this.searchQuery = '';
    this.searchQueryControl = new Control();
    //...

    this.searchQueryControl
        .valueChanges
        .debounceTime(1000)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .subscribe(text => {

            if(text !== '') {
              this.searchQuery = text;
              this.search();
            }
      });

    //...
}
```

By doing that, we would only run the code when the input has changed (`this.searchQueryControl.valueChanges`), and when there hasn't been another change within 1 second (`.debounceTime(1000)`). The `distinctUntilChanged()` allow us to run the code if the value is different to the last time it ran. So if the user typed 'asd', hit the backspace key and then retyped the ending 'd' again, nothing would happen.

Comment: This solution works, but the only issue is that it changes the behavior a little bit. For example, on an android device, I would normally press the search button in the keyboard to start searching(keyup.enter). I think it is a little awkward (just my personal thought). Thank for the solution, i will consider it!